# Deleting every second row in a csv-file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am new to d3.js. Right now i am working on a linechart with `d3.js` and would like to delete/ignore every second row of my original csv-file. The amount of data is very high and I want to try, if Zoom and Pan will get less laggy with less data. Since the original has very small data steps the end result would be the same.

I'm getting my data with 
`d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;...`

and

`function type(d) {
d.x = +d.Time_seconds;
d.y1 = +d.Temp2_C;
d.y2 = +d.Temp3_C;`

I think a possible solution could be deleting the rows, before loading them with `d3.csv()`

I have already tried something with `d3.xhr`, but didnt get anything useful of it. I dont even know, if its the right way to start.

Thank you!

Comment: We recommend sharing the code you've tried so far. Otherwise it's very hard to understand or explain what's needed.

Answer (score 2):

after you get the data in the load callback use `Array.filter` and use the index to determine if the row is accepted

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data = data.filter( (e, i) => i % 2 === 0 );

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me a lot. 

Would there be also a way to use only each tenth datapoint?

I've got data points from 0 to 1000 in steps of 0.01 so it wouldnt matter if i shorten my data and use like only every tenth point, or even less.
But with the way you showed me i get only one datapoint every 2 seconds. Thats maybe not enought in terms of accuracy.

Comment: Is you csv file `100*1000 = 100000` lines big? If you look in your csv file are the rows are nicely 0.01 seconds apart and using the browser debugger it also looks correct (100000 rows in `data`) and 0.01 seconds apart, how many rows do you have after the code line with `filter()`. If you used `2` in the modulo expression then it should be 50000.

Comment: Found the mistake.
I used the `filter()` on my first column, not on the data in general. I should have just done, what you suggested!

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: If you get a suggestion of what line of code to add or change why do you not try this suggestion first instead of doing something completely different and then asking that it does not work without showing your own modification?

Comment: Because I'm a noob in d3.js and didnt do something _complete different_ on purpose. Thanks for your help anyway.